# Why cout<<hex satement makes the rest print in hex format only

Tags: c++, hex, cout

I have following code snippets to print hex value of an integer,

```
int i=10;
cout<<hex<<i<<endl;
```

and which prints hex value of 10 `a` on console well,

but the on the next line I need to print the decimal value of another variable, like

```
  int j=11;
  cout<<j<<endl;
```

but it also prints the hex value of 11, `b`, and if I used  `cout<<dec<<j<<endl;` it prints the decimal  value.

Also I noticed that all the `cout` prints the hex value of variable if used `cout<<hex` before.

So my question is it normal behavior? Do I need to use `<<dec` if I used `<<hex` once before ?

Comment: Ya, I believe you have to do the `<<dec` or `<<hex` if you want to switch it. If I remember correctly, what you're doing is setting a flag to print out in hex or decimal, and it will keep that flag until it is set to something else.

Comment: Yes, you have to reset it to `std::dec` (technically clear the `std::ios_base::basefield` bitmask which would still have the bits for `std::ios_base::hex` set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `dec` in order to `cout` decimal values, because `hex` is a "sticky" manipulator (like many other manipulators by the way) - it will stay until changed.

Answer (score 2):

You might write your own manipulator to overcome the 'sticky' behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

// Hex
// ============================================================================

template <typename T>
struct Hex
{
    enum { Width = (std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + 1) / 4 };
    const T& value;
    const int width;

    Hex(const T& value, int width = Width)
    : value(value), width(width)
    {}

    void write(std::ostream& stream) const {
        if(std::numeric_limits<T>::radix != 2) stream << value;
        else {
            std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = stream.setf(
                std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
            char fill = stream.fill('0');
            stream << "0x" << std::setw(width) << value;
            stream.fill(fill);
            stream.setf(flags, std::ios_base::basefield);
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline Hex<T> hex(const T& value, int width = Hex<T>::Width) {
    return Hex<T>(value, width);
}

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Hex<T>& value) {
    value.write(stream);
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned short i = 0xa;
    std::cout << hex(i) << " == " << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cout is a global. Shifting in the manipulator modifies the state of that global. Given you can chain the manipulators together, the instance of cout would never know when to "unset" it. So, it persists.